# Reverse multiple strings separated by comma

Tags: beginner, strings, brainfuck

Recently I did a lot of practice problems in brainfuck to learn better about how to use it (and to get more competent in general). Today I write a program to manipulate the input such that every word (separated by comma `,`) is printed in reverse, while the commas are kept in place, which I'm quite proud of. Example provided in the statement: **Input:** `Hello,world\0` **Output:** `olleH,dlrow`

Feel free to rip my code (and comments as well) apart and give some pointers on how my code could be improved!

```
>, 1:read
[ ~a:varchar a:in
[>+>+<<-] a:0 b:c:in
>>>>++++[<+++++ +++++ +>-]<[<->-] a:0 b:in [c:in-44]
<[[-]<[<+>-]>>] if c then a:in else
<[<<[.<]>[>]>.>]< print reverse then comma
, redo a':read ]
<[.<] print reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

Upon learning more brainfuck, I've learned that my loop that subtracts 44 could be improved:

#### Before

```
>> tmp2=0 ++++[< tmp1=0 +++++ +++++ + >-] tmp1 is 44
<[<->-] subtract tmp1 from ptr
```

#### After

```
>  tmp1=0 ++++[< ptr    ----- ----- - >-]
```

This prevents actually creating the value 44 and performing an additional ~44 operations.

Answer (score 4):

## Optimizations

The additional memory in `c-44` isn't necessary, as you can just subtract 4 times eleven directly from `c`.

## Comment consistency

Apart from the minimal optimization your *code* is fine. Your *comments* aren't, to be honest.

There isn't a best-practice or a style guide for brainfuck as far as I know, but the problem stems from the inconsistency. In the first line, it starts with `1:read`. It's not completely clear what that means, so I'll go with "read into cell 1". `1` immediately gets renamed to `a`:

```
[ ~a:varchar a:in
```

The squiggly line (`~`) and the `varchar` aren't self-explaining, but the `a:in` is. So we get the expectation that `<var>:<value>` will be a pattern.

That pattern breaks down in the next line, where `a:0` (follows the pattern), but `b:c:in`:

```
[>+>+<<-] a:0 b:c:in
```

The line afterwards introduces brackets, which are valid brainfuck instructions:

```
>>>>++++[<+++++ +++++ +>-]<[<->-] a:0 b:in [c:in-44]
```

We've now mixed comments and code. It's nod bad in this case, since we're on `d:0` either way, but it's an error waiting to happen.

However, the real kicker is the next line

```
<[[-]<[<+>-]>>] if c then a:in else
```

It's missing `b:(in or 0) c:0 d:0`, which is essential for the line afterwards, since we're at position `c` or `d` after this line. If you really want to manage this style, I'd suggest to

- add an asterisk to the current cell and
- use a fixed starting position for the comments:

```
[-][
Used names:

  a : current cell at beginning of loop
  b : cell after a to contain a copy of a
  c : cell after b to subtract 44 from a
  d : cell after c as helper to subtract 44 from c
  in: current loop input

  *<cell>: current cell
 *?<cell>: cell position depends on values
]

>,                        *a:in
[                         *a:in
[>+>+<<-]                 *a:0        b:in         c:in
>>>++++[<----- ----- ->-]  a:0        b:in         c:(in minus 44)   *d:0
<[[-]<[<+>-]>>]            a:(c?in:0) b:(c?0:44) *?c:0              *?d:0
.....
```

I wouldn't recommend that to be honest, as it gets hard to manage after a while. However, it's *consistent*.

## Documentation can be full text

But we can just comment our code like in a regular programming language:

```
[-]
[
This program reverses the words in a list of comma separated words.
It's memory usage is bound by the input string.
]

We leave the initial cell empty so that every word is 0 limited:

>,

[
    Our initial loop cell A contains the input which we immediately
    shove into the next two cells B and C:

    [>+>+<<-]

    A : 0      (current position)
    B : input
    C : input
    D : temporarily 4 to subtract 44 from C

    We now subtract 44 from C:
    >>>++++[<----- ----- ->-]

    If our input was NOT a comma (44) C won't be zero and we move
    B back into A and set B and C to zero:

    <[[-]<[<+>-]>>]

    We're now either at position C (if C was zero) or position D
    (if C wasn't zero); if C was zero then B will contain a comma
    and A is zero; the next loop will therefore get executed

    Otherwise we're at position D and simply move back to position
    B to write the next letter of the word

    <[<<[.<]>[>]>.>]<
,]

The last word is limited by zero so we just print the letters backwards:
<[.<]
```

This is an ***exaggeration***, but you can be as verbose as you like. This kind of commenting has a big draw back, though: it's easy to accidentally enter a comma or period by mistake and end up with broken code.

## Conclusion

All in all, well done. The if-else-logic is a nice brain teaser, to be honest, which makes an proper comments a lot more important.