# AST-based Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, interpreter, brainfuck

Since implementing my [Interactive Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/interactive-brainfuck-interpreter-in-haskell) I figured that it would be a good idea to build upon an Abstract Syntax Tree. I have also decided to drop replacing the `IO` monad by some other structure for the time being as what I have now works fine, and fast.

The code consists of the following:

- The main application
- The tape
- The application

**Main.hs**

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import System.Environment

import Interpreter

data SimpleOption = ShowProgram | ShowMemory deriving (Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)
data AdvancedOption = Program | File deriving (Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)
data Options = Options [SimpleOption] (Map.Map AdvancedOption String) deriving (Show)

addSimpleOption :: SimpleOption -> Options -> Options
addSimpleOption opt (Options sOpts aOpts) = Options (opt:sOpts) aOpts

addAdvancedOption :: AdvancedOption -> String -> Options -> Options
addAdvancedOption opt val (Options sOpts aOpts) = Options sOpts (Map.insert opt val aOpts)

isOptionsEmpty :: Options -> Bool
isOptionsEmpty (Options sOpts aOpts) = null sOpts && Map.null aOpts

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case parseArgs args (Options [] Map.empty) >>= validateOptions of
        Left err    -> putStrLn err
        Right opts  -> execute opts

execute :: Options -> IO ()
execute opts@(Options sOpts _) = do
    program <- getProgram opts
    (program', memory) <- interpret program
    when (ShowProgram `elem` sOpts) $ putStrLn ("\n" ++ show program')
    when (ShowMemory `elem` sOpts) $ putStrLn ("\n" ++ show memory)

getProgram :: Options -> IO String
getProgram (Options _ aOpts) = case Map.lookup Program aOpts of
    Nothing         -> case Map.lookup File aOpts of
        Just file       -> readFile file
    Just program    -> return program

parseArgs :: [String] -> Options -> Either String Options
parseArgs [] opts                   = if isOptionsEmpty opts then Left usage else Right opts
parseArgs [program] opts            = Right $ addAdvancedOption Program program opts
parseArgs ("-sp":args) opts         = parseArgs args (addSimpleOption ShowProgram opts)
parseArgs ("-sm":args) opts         = parseArgs args (addSimpleOption ShowMemory opts)
parseArgs ("-p":program:args) opts  = parseArgs args (addAdvancedOption Program program opts)
parseArgs ("-f":file:args) opts     = parseArgs args (addAdvancedOption File file opts)
parseArgs _ _                       = Left usage

usage :: String
usage = "Usage: bf-interpreter-ast-exe [-sp] [-sm] [-f file] [-p program | program]"

validateOptions :: Options -> Either String Options
validateOptions opts@(Options _ aOpts)
| Program `Map.member` aOpts && File `Map.member` aOpts   = Left "Error: Only one of the options File and Program can be present"
| Program `Map.member` aOpts || File `Map.member` aOpts   = Right opts
| otherwise                                               = Left "Error: One of the options File and Program must be present"
```

**Tape.hs**

```
module Tape
    ( Tape(..)
    , makeTape
    , forwardTape
    , reverseTape
    , tapeValue
    , onTapeValue
    ) where

data Tape a = Tape [a] !a [a] deriving (Eq)

instance Show a => Show (Tape a) where
    show (Tape ls v rs) = show (reverse ls) ++ " " ++ show v ++ " " ++  show rs

makeTape :: a -> Tape a
makeTape def = Tape [] def []

forwardTape :: a -> Tape a -> Tape a
forwardTape def (Tape ls v [])  = Tape (v:ls) def []
forwardTape _ (Tape ls v rs)    = Tape (v:ls) (head rs) (tail rs)

reverseTape :: a -> Tape a -> Tape a
reverseTape def (Tape [] v rs)  = Tape [] def (v:rs)
reverseTape _ (Tape ls v rs)    = Tape (tail ls) (head ls) (v:rs)

tapeValue :: Tape a -> a
tapeValue (Tape _ v _) = v

onTapeValue :: (a -> a) -> Tape a -> Tape a
onTapeValue func (Tape ls v rs) = Tape ls (func v) rs
```

**Interpreter.hs**

```
module Interpreter
    ( interpret
    ) where

import Data.Word
import System.IO

import Tape

data BFInstruction = MemoryRight | MemoryLeft | Increment | Decrement | Output | Input | Loop [BFInstruction] deriving (Eq, Show)
type BFProgram = [BFInstruction]

newtype BFMemoryCell = BFMemoryCell Word8 deriving (Eq, Show)
type BFMemory = Tape BFMemoryCell

cellValue :: BFMemoryCell -> Word8
cellValue (BFMemoryCell val) = val

onCellValue :: (Word8 -> Word8) -> BFMemoryCell -> BFMemoryCell
onCellValue func (BFMemoryCell val) = BFMemoryCell $ func val

makeProgram :: String -> BFProgram
makeProgram = makeProgram'

makeProgram' :: String -> BFProgram
makeProgram' "" = []
makeProgram' (x:xs) = case x of
    '>' -> continue MemoryRight
    '<' -> continue MemoryLeft
    '+' -> continue Increment
    '-' -> continue Decrement
    '.' -> continue Output
    ',' -> continue Input
    '[' -> do
        let (loop, rest) = splitOnLoopEnd xs
        Loop (makeProgram loop):makeProgram' rest
    ']' -> []
    _   -> makeProgram' xs
    where
        continue instr = instr:makeProgram' xs

splitOnLoopEnd :: String -> (String, String)
splitOnLoopEnd = splitOnLoopEnd' 0

splitOnLoopEnd' :: Int -> String -> (String, String)
splitOnLoopEnd' _ "" = error "No matching ] found"
splitOnLoopEnd' 0 (']':xs') = ([], xs')
splitOnLoopEnd' nesting (x:xs') = case x of
    ']' -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next (subtract 1)
    '[' -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next (+1)
    _   -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next id
    where
        next func = splitOnLoopEnd' (func nesting) xs'

interpret :: String -> IO (BFProgram, BFMemory)
interpret input = do
    let program = makeProgram input
    let memory = makeTape (BFMemoryCell 0)
    memory' <- execute program memory
    return (program, memory')

execute :: BFProgram -> BFMemory -> IO BFMemory
execute [] memory = return memory
execute xs@(x:xs') memory = case x of
    MemoryRight     -> continue $ forwardTape (BFMemoryCell 0) memory
    MemoryLeft      -> continue $ reverseTape (BFMemoryCell 0) memory
    Increment       -> continue $ onTapeValue (onCellValue (+1)) memory
    Decrement       -> continue $ onTapeValue (onCellValue (subtract 1)) memory
    Output          -> do
        putChar $ toEnum . fromEnum . cellValue . tapeValue $ memory
        hFlush stdout
        continue memory
    Input           -> do
        ch <- getChar
        continue $ onTapeValue (\_ -> BFMemoryCell . toEnum . fromEnum $ ch) memory
    Loop program'   -> if cellValue (tapeValue memory) == 0
        then continue memory
        else do
            memory' <- execute program' memory
            execute xs memory'
    where
        continue = execute xs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Prefer pattern matching over `head`/`tail`

Your `forwardTape` and `reverseTape` both use `head` and `tail`. This can lead to empty list errors if you accidentally swap the lines:

```
forwardTape _ (Tape ls v rs)    = Tape (v:ls) (head rs) (tail rs) -- woops
forwardTape def (Tape ls v [])  = Tape (v:ls) def []
```

Your completely prevent this error if you use pattern matching instead:

```
forwardTape _ (Tape ls v (r:rs)) = Tape (v:ls) r rs 
forwardTape def (Tape ls v [])   = Tape (v:ls) def []
```

If you don't like to be explicit in `forwardTape` and `reverseTape` use a helper:

```
safeUncons :: a -> [a] -> (a, [a])
safeUncons _ (x:xs) = (x, xs)
safeUncons d []     = (d, [])

forwardTape, reverseTape :: a -> Tape a -> Tape a
forwardTape d (Tape ls v rs) = let (x, xs) = safeUncons d rs in Tape (v:ls) x xs
reverseTape d (Tape ls v rs) = let (x, xs) = safeUncons d ls in Tape xs x (v:rs)
```

## Use `do` notation for monads and monads only<sup>*</sup>

`do` notation is syntactical sugar for `>>` and `>>=`. If you have

```
do a
   b
   x <- c
   let y = 3
   d x y
```

it gets desugared into

```
a >> b >> c >>= (\x -> let y = 3 in d x y)
```

So when you use `do`, other Haskellers will try to figure out what monad is currently getting used. However, you don't use a monad at all:

```
    '[' -> do
        let (loop, rest) = splitOnLoopEnd xs
        Loop (makeProgram loop):makeProgram' rest
```

That's the same as

```
    '[' -> 
        let (loop, rest) = splitOnLoopEnd xs
        in Loop (makeProgram loop):makeProgram' rest
```

If possible, prefer the latter style. [`do` expressions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) are meant as "conventional syntax for monadic programming", after all.

## Make it hard to use functions wrong or in the wrong context

`splitOnLoopEnd'` should **never** get used outside of `splitOnLoopEnd`. Unless you want to explicitly test `splitOnLoopEnd'` I don't recommend to use a top-level binding:

```
splitOnLoopEnd :: String -> (String, String)
splitOnLoopEnd = go 0
  where
    go _ "" = error "No matching ] found"
    go 0 (']':xs') = ([], xs')
    go nesting (x:xs') = case x of
      ']' -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next (nesting - 1)
      '[' -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next (nesting + 1)
      _   -> (x:ys, zs) where (ys, zs) = next nesting
      where
          next n = go n xs'
```

Also note that I changed `next` argument. It's a lot harder to use a `Int` wrong compared to a `Int -> Int`. While we're at it, let's reorder some parts and get ri of the `'` after `xs`:

```
splitOnLoopEnd :: String -> (String, String)
splitOnLoopEnd = go 0
  where
    go _ "" = error "No matching ] found"
    go 0 (']':xs) = ([], xs)
    go n (x:xs)   = let (ys, zs) = go (n + l) xs in (x:ys, zs)
      where
          l = case x of
              ']' -> (-1)
              '[' -> 1
              _   -> 0
```

We can use `case … of` just for the nesting difference, which removes the repetition of `next`.

By the way, `makeProgram` and `makeProgram'` do the same. I suggest to rename the latter to the former. Probably a remnant from a previous version.

## Provide more power to the user

At the moment, your user cannot work with the AST since it doesn't get exported. They can't even use the type `BFProgram`. They can use the values, though. So let us have a look at the power a user should have.

### Export types (but not necessarily their constructors)

If I have a malfunctioning `BFProgram`, I would like to dump it at some point. I would write

```
dumpProgram :: BFProgram -> IO ()
```

or similar. However, that's not possible at the moment, since `BFProgram` never gets exported. I have to write

```
dumpProgram :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

which might be to general for my preference. It's fine to provide the user the types, though:

```
module Interpreter
    ( interpret
    , parse
    , execute
    , BFProgram
    , BFMemory
    , BFMemoryCell
    , BFInstruction
    ) where
```

This will only export the *type*, not the *constructors*, though, so I'm not able to generate a new `BFInstruction`. I can only reuse already existing ones.

### Use canonical names

Your `makeProgram` is a *parser*, therefore I suggest you to call it `parse` instead:

```
parse :: String -> BFProgram
```

While you're at it, use `Either e BFProgram` instead of `error`. That way you can recover from parsing errors.

### Provide modular functionality.

Your `interpret` variant forces the user to keep the original source. But that's not necessary if the user wants to run the program several times. So instead, I suggest you to provide both `parse` and `execute`. You have to change `execute`'s type slightly:

```
execute :: BFProgram -> IO BFMemory
execute = executeWith (makeTape (BFMemoryCell 0))

executeWith :: BFMemory -> BFProgram -> IO BFMemory
executeWith = -- your old execute implementation
```

That way one can easily run the same program multiple times:

```
helloWorldProgram <- parse <$> readFile "hello.bf"
replicateM_ 10 $ execute helloWorldProgram
```

You can keep the `interpret` functionality as a "one does all", but for testing and maintenance it's easier to provide a larger interface.

## Do not reinvent the wheel (unless you want to)

There are several libraries that provide argument parsers, for example [`optparse-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative). Those libraries make it easy to handle command line arguments without a hassle.

Also, a `Map` for two possible option variants is slightly an overkill:

```
data Source  = Program String | File FilePath | StdIn

data Options = Options {
               showProgram :: Bool,
               showMemory  :: Bool,
               sourceCode  :: Source
               } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

That's all you need for your current options. Your program needs **all** of them set, especially the `sourceCode`. An `optparse-applicative` parser could look like this:

```
source :: Parser Source
source = program <|> file <|> pure stdin

file :: Parser Source
file = File <$> strOption
  (  long "file"
  <> short 'f'
  <> metavar "FILENAME"
  <> help "Brainfuck file" )

program :: Parser Source
program = Program <$> strOption
  (  long "program"
  <> short 'p'
  <> metavar "PROGRAM"
  <> help "Brainfuck source code" )

stdin :: Parser Source
stdin = flag' StdIn
  (  long "stdin"
  <> help "Read from stdin" )

options :: Parser Options
options = Options 
       <$> switch
          ( long "show-program"
         <> short 'p'
         <> help "Show the parsed program before execution" )
       <*> switch
          ( long "show-memory"
         <> short 'm'
         <> help "Show the memory tape after execution" )
       <*> source
```

Note that this also generate a help message.

## Other remarks

Apart from the remarks mentioned above, well done. The tape movements are now \$\mathcal O(1)\$, and the same holds for jumping to the start or end of a loop. Your AST cannot represent invalid programs, which is a *big* plus compared to your previous approach.

There are some points where I would use another style, but that's personal preference, e.g.

```
execute program' memory >>= execute xs
```

I usually keep the number of prime functions or variables down, too, and use them only if they were derived from the original one, e.g.

```
execute p@(x:xs) --  vs  -- execute xs@(x:xs')
```

But again, that's personal preference.

If you want to upload your package at some point you should add some documentation and use some other module names, but I don't think you're going to publish it on Hackage.

The only other improvement I can think of is optimization, which needs a modified AST, and testing, which needs a non-`IO` variant.

---

<sup>* Technically also for Applicative, but that needs an extension, so don't.</sup>

Comment: Is there anyway to not have to traverse the code multiple times when parsing loop constructs? A loop section is 1 + nesting level times if I understand correctly.